# Why is the exception "IllegalArgumentException: Missing closing quote on line '"'"

Tags: scala, sbt, jline

When I run `sbt` from my unix prompt, I get the following after every command inside the console.

```
[WARN] Unable to parse user configuration: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing closing quote on line '"'
        at jline.console.ConsoleKeys.loadKeys(ConsoleKeys.java:173)
        at jline.console.ConsoleKeys.loadKeys(ConsoleKeys.java:73)
        at jline.console.ConsoleKeys.<init>(ConsoleKeys.java:35)
```

Could anyone hint, point me to what's wrong?

Comment: Could you give us your sbt file?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to sbt. May I know what's an sbt file?

Comment: Usually it locates in the root path of your project, named `build.sbt`

Comment: @user247077, what [Herrington Darkholme](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2198656/herrington-darkholme) said and it can also mean your Build.scala (or any .scala file that contains sbt project definitions) in your source' project folder.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have an empty directory, with only a codeFile.scala inside it. (Although the same error also shows up in my play projects...)

Comment: How did you install sbt? What OS do you use? I *guess* the issue may be related to `jline.terminal` system property that's incorrectly set for the command line.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski
I'm using Mint 16. 
For standalone sbt: I downloaded the tgz and use the .jar from scala. 
For the one with play, it came with play, so no installation

Comment: @HerringtonDarkholme  Answered your question.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you rename `$HOME/.inputrc` if you've got one - see  https://github.com/jline/jline2/wiki/Using-JLine#startup.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski These were the offending lines in my .inputrc. Not sure why! I had these commented out but were still causing issues.
`
    `#"^[OR":"mutt^M"`
    `#"^[[13~":"mutt^M"`
`
Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Here comes the answer! Accept if it helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbt uses JLine for terminal handling and it appears that your issue might be with `$HOME/.inputrc` that's read by JLine at startup as described in [the documentation of JLine](https://github.com/jline/jline2/wiki/Using-JLine#startup):

> Next, the file $HOME/.inputrc is read.
>
> JLine does attempt honor as many of the settings in your .inputrc file
>   as possible, including conditional settings (for example, binding a
>   specific key only if being run withing a specific program).